# How to refactor a very large Event Class in Jetpack compose

Tags: mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, clean-architecture

I'm using a sealed class to classify user events and send to viewModel's onEvent function so that handle them but since I have some sort of form Composable in my screen's BottomSheet both my `onEvent` function which is in viewModel to handle events and `PairDetailEvent` class had very largen when app is scaled so I think it is a bad practice to have this large of sealed class and also that much branches in an onEvent function, so if there is a way or best practice to follow to maintain readability i wanna know that.

I tried to apply practices in [this](https://youtu.be/8YPXv7xKh2w?t=3100) video by the way

Thanks in advance.

---

**PairDetailEvent class :**

```kotlin
sealed class PairDetailScreenEvent {
    data class SaveAnalyze(val pairId: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class DeleteImageFromAnalyze(val analyzeId: String, val index: Int, val pairId: String, val chartUrlList: List<String>) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class DeleteAnalyze(val analyzeId: String, val pairId: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class AddNewSectionToUrlList(val index: Int) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EnterUrl(val value: String, val index: Int) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class AddOrRemoveChip(val chipId: Int) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EditAnalyze(val analyzeId: String, val currentPairId: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class GetAnalysis(val currentPairId: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class UpdateLongOrShort(val isLong: Boolean) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EnterNote(val value: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EnterResult(val value: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EnterPositionAmount(val value: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EnterStopLossPrice(val value: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EnterEntryPrice(val value: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EnterClosingPrice(val value: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class EnterReason(val value: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    data class TurnOnEditAnalyzeMode(val analyzeId: String, val currentPairId: String) : PairDetailScreenEvent()
    object ResetState : PairDetailScreenEvent()
}
```

**onEvent function in viewModel :**

```kotlin
    fun onEvent(event: PairDetailScreenEvent) {
        when (event) {
            is PairDetailScreenEvent.DeleteAnalyze -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    analyzeRepository.deleteAnalyzeFromFirebase(
                        analyzeId = event.analyzeId,
                        pairId = event.pairId
                    )
                }
            }


            is PairDetailScreenEvent.SaveAnalyze -> {
                submitFormForValidation()
                val chartUrlValidationResult =
                    validationUseCases.validateChartUrls.execute(state.value.chartUrlList)

                if (chartUrlValidationResult.successful && state.value.isValidationSuccess) {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        try {

                            analyzeRepository.saveAnalyze(
                                analyze = AnalyzeModel(
                                    reason = state.value.entryReasonText,
                                    result = state.value.resultText,
                                    chartUrlList = fetchIdOfImageFromURL(state.value.chartUrlList),
                                    notes = state.value.notesText,
                                    stopLossPrice = state.value.stopLossPrice.toDouble(),
                                    entryPrice = state.value.entryPrice.toDouble(),
                                    closingPrice = state.value.closingPrice.toDouble(),
                                    positionAmountInDollars = state.value.positionAmountInDollars.toDouble(),
                                    long = state.value.isLong,
                                    moodChips = state.value.moodChips.toList()
                                ),
                                currentPairId = event.pairId
                            )
                            _validationEvent.emit(true)
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            // TODO:
                        }
                    }

                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            chartUrlList = listOf(""),
                            entryReasonText = "",
                            resultText = "",
                            notesText = "",
                            stopLossPrice = "",
                            entryPrice = "",
                            positionAmountInDollars = "",
                            closingPrice = "",
                            isValidationSuccess = false
                        )
                    }


                } else {
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        if (chartUrlValidationResult.errorMessage != null)
                            _eventChannel.send(
                                UiText.StringResource(chartUrlValidationResult.errorMessage)
                            )
                    }
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EnterNote -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        notesText = event.value
                    )
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EnterReason -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        entryReasonText = event.value
                    )
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EnterResult -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        resultText = event.value
                    )
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EnterUrl -> {
                chartUrlList[event.index] = event.value.trim()
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        chartUrlList = chartUrlList.toList()
                    )
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.AddNewSectionToUrlList -> {
                chartUrlList.add(event.index, "")
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        chartUrlList = chartUrlList.toList()
                    )
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.DeleteImageFromAnalyze -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    analyzeRepository.deleteImageFromAnalyze(
                        event.analyzeId,
                        event.index,
                        event.pairId,
                        event.chartUrlList
                    )
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EnterClosingPrice -> {
                println("event.value ${event.value}")
                println("state.closinPrice ${state.value.closingPrice}")
                println("state.tempString ${state.value.tempString}")
                try {
                    if (event.value.toDoubleOrNull() != null)
                        _state.update {
                            it.copy(
                                closingPrice = event.value,
                                tempString = ""
                            )
                        }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            tempString = event.value
                        )
                    }
                    viewModelScope.launch {
                        _eventChannel.send(
                            UiText.DynamicString("Girlen sayı geçerli değil")
                        )
                    }
                }

            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EnterEntryPrice -> {
                if (event.value.toDoubleOrNull() != null)
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            entryPrice = event.value,
                        )
                    }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EnterPositionAmount -> {
                if (event.value.toDoubleOrNull() != null)
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            positionAmountInDollars = event.value,
                        )
                    }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EnterStopLossPrice -> {
                if (event.value.toDoubleOrNull() != null)
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            stopLossPrice = event.value,
                        )
                    }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.TurnOnEditAnalyzeMode -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {

                    analyzeRepository.getAnalyzeById(event.analyzeId, event.currentPairId)
                        .collect { analyzeResult ->

                            when (analyzeResult) {
                                is Resource.Loading -> {
                                    _state.update {
                                        it.copy(
                                            isLoading = true
                                        )
                                    }
                                }

                                is Resource.Success -> {

                                    _state.update {
                                        it.copy(
                                            updatingAnalyze = analyzeResult.data,
                                            isLoading = false,
                                            isInEditMode = true,
                                            moodChips = analyzeResult.data?.moodChips!!.toMutableSet(),
                                            chartUrlList = convertBackToActualChartURL(analyzeResult.data.chartUrlList),
                                            isLong = analyzeResult.data.long,
                                            entryReasonText = analyzeResult.data.reason,
                                            resultText = analyzeResult.data.result,
                                            notesText = analyzeResult.data.notes,
                                            stopLossPrice = analyzeResult.data.stopLossPrice.toString(),
                                            entryPrice = analyzeResult.data.entryPrice.toString(),
                                            closingPrice = analyzeResult.data.closingPrice.toString(),
                                            positionAmountInDollars = analyzeResult.data.positionAmountInDollars.toString(),
                                        )
                                    }
                                }

                                is Resource.Error -> {
                                    _state.update {
                                        it.copy(
                                            isLoading = false,
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }

            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.ResetState -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        updatingAnalyze = null,
                        isLoading = false,
                        isInEditMode = false,
                        moodChips = emptySet<Int>().toMutableSet(),
                        chartUrlList = listOf(""),
                        isLong = false,
                        isValidationSuccess = false,
                        entryReasonText = "",
                        resultText = "",
                        notesText = "",
                        stopLossPrice = "",
                        stopLossPriceError = null,
                        entryPrice = "",
                        entryPriceError = null,
                        closingPrice = "",
                        closingPriceError = null,
                        positionAmountInDollars = "",
                        positionAmountInDollarsError = null
                    )
                }

            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.AddOrRemoveChip -> {
                if (!_state.value.moodChips.contains(event.chipId))
                    _state.value.moodChips.add(event.chipId)
                else
                    _state.value.moodChips.remove(event.chipId)
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.UpdateLongOrShort -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        isLong = event.isLong
                    )
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.EditAnalyze -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    analyzeRepository.editAnalyze(
                        currentPairId = event.currentPairId,
                        analyzeId = event.analyzeId,
                        analyze = _state.value.updatingAnalyze!!.copy(
                            reason = state.value.entryReasonText,
                            result = state.value.resultText,
                            notes = state.value.notesText,
                            chartUrlList = fetchIdOfImageFromURL(state.value.chartUrlList),
                            positionAmountInDollars = state.value.positionAmountInDollars.toDouble(),
                            stopLossPrice = state.value.stopLossPrice.toDouble(),
                            entryPrice = state.value.entryPrice.toDouble(),
                            closingPrice = state.value.closingPrice.toDouble(),
                            long = state.value.isLong,
                            moodChips = state.value.moodChips.toList()
                        )
                    ).collect()

                    _validationEvent.emit(true)
                }
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        updatingAnalyze = null,
                        isLoading = false,
                        isInEditMode = false,
                        moodChips = emptySet<Int>().toMutableSet(),
                        chartUrlList = listOf(""),
                        isLong = false,
                        isValidationSuccess = false,
                        entryReasonText = "",
                        resultText = "",
                        notesText = "",
                        stopLossPrice = "",
                        stopLossPriceError = null,
                        entryPrice = "",
                        entryPriceError = null,
                        closingPrice = "",
                        closingPriceError = null,
                        positionAmountInDollars = "",
                        positionAmountInDollarsError = null
                    )
                }
            }

            is PairDetailScreenEvent.GetAnalysis -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isLoading = true
                        )
                    }
                    delay(1.seconds)
                    getAnalyzeList(event.currentPairId)
                    _state.update {
                        it.copy(
                            isLoading = false
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```